# looking for a utility to test DHCP settings

Tags: networking, dhcp

Iv'e recently installed DHCP server (`isc-dhcp-server`) in my workplace.

I'm looking for a utility to test the network DHCP settings from a remote machine (**not by using `dhclient` / `iptables /renew`**).

- indication of the responding server (sometimes my colleagues install by mistake DHCP services)
- the ability to provide a MAC address (to test pool reservations)
- simple display of the response

**for example:**

```
$> [utility name] [source mac address | optional] ...

RESPONSE (DHCP Server is 192.168....)
    IP: 192.168.....
    SUBNET: 255.255.....
    DEFAULT GATEWAY: 192.168.....
    ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try out the "dhcping" utility. On CentOS/RHEL, you'll have the option to "yum install it" after you'll gain connectivity to the EPEL repository. Check out the command options. They seem really relevant for your needs.

```
dhcping(8)                  General Commands Manual                 dhcping(8)

NAME
   dhcping - send a DHCP request to DHCP server to see if it’s up and running

SYNOPSIS
   dhcping [-v] [-q] [-i] [-r] -t maxwait -c client-IP-address -s server-IP-address -h client-hardware-address [-g gateway-
   IP-address]

DESCRIPTION
   This command allows the system administrator to check if a remote DHCP server is still functioning.

   Options are:

   -v   Verbose, print some information.

   -i   Use DHCPINFORM packets.

   -r   Use DHCPREQUEST packets (default behaviour).

   -q   Quiet, print nothing on the screen.

   -t maxwait
        Maximum time to wait for an answer from the server in seconds.  Default is 3 seconds.

   -c client-IP-address
        Request this IP address. Note that this is also the IP address the answer will be sent to.

   -s server-IP-address
        Send the DHCP packet to this IP address.

   -h client-hardware-address
        Use this hardware-address in the DHCP request. It can be up to sixteen octets seperated by colons (i.e. 01:02:03:04)

   -g gateway-IP-address
        Use this IP address for the gateway IP address in the DHCP packet.  This option is currently broken
```

All the best!

+Daniel.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread but for all its worth, my vote goes to http://blog.thecybershadow.net/2013/01/10/dhcp-test-client/
From the blog:

> While trying to set up my home network, I was dismayed that there was
>   no simple way to test the DHCP server. Snooping packets is limited to
>   examining existing traffic.
>
> DHCP test tools exist (DHCPing and dhquery), however, both are
>   outdated and don’t work with the latest versions of their
>   requirements, and both won’t work on Windows.
>
> I’ve written a simple DHCP “client” which can receive and decode
>   broadcasted DHCP replies, as well as send out DHCP “discover” packets.
>   The tool is cross-platform and should work on Windows and major POSIX
>   systems.

I've downloaded it from https://github.com/CyberShadow/dhcptest and compiled it. He provides compiled versions for windows but on Linux you have to compile it yourself which is very easy with good instructions.